# RFC syntax definition

Tags: syntax, specifications, definition

I would like to bring our specifications to a better level of fine-grained definition of syntaxes, semantics and the like. I read my fair share of RFCs and just love the way they define things like "how an email adress looks like" or "what a correct URL is".

But, I haven't yet found a definition of the syntax of those definitions. Like, e.g. how do you define optional parts? How do you define repetition? How to correctly define alternatives (`/` vs `|`)

Is there an RFC that defines the syntax all those other RFCs use to define their actual domain-specific definitions that I could adapt to our specifications?

Comment: RFC 3285 [Using Microsoft Word to create Internet Drafts and RFCs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3285), RFC 5385 [Version 2.0 Microsoft Word Template...](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5385). Posting as a comment because I don't want to rep-whore answering [low quality questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

Comment: I don't really see how this qualifies as a low quality question

Comment: same as at Stack Overflow, "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam..."

Comment: I am not asking for a tool, nor a library and neither a *favorite* off-site resource. I am asking for a legitimate RFC that defines the formal standards of defining RFC syntax (which, btw, neither of yours do, they merely define how an RFC has to look like, but not how the syntax of definitions is). I believe this can be answered objectively because there is no room for dicussion anwhere. Either there is an RFC doing this, or there is not. Nothing to interpret or have opinions on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammar formalism used in many modern RFCs is called *Augmented Backus-Naur-Form*, and is specified in [RFC 5234 – Augmented BNF for Syntax Specifications: ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234):

> Internet technical specifications often need to define a formal syntax.  Over the years, a modified version of Backus-Naur Form (BNF), called Augmented BNF (ABNF), has been popular among many Internet specifications.  The current specification documents ABNF. It balances compactness and simplicity with reasonable representational power.  The differences between standard BNF and ABNF involve naming rules, repetition, alternatives, order-independence, and value ranges.  This specification also supplies additional rule definitions and encoding for a core lexical analyzer of the type common to several Internet specifications.